# Find Microsoft team link connected to a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-teams

From a team in Microsoft Teams I can select "Open in SharePoint" to go to the SharePoint site used for the team.

But if I find the SharePoint site first, how would I find/go to the associated team and its channels?

There is no link called "Teams" in the left-menu navigation(quick launch area) on the SharePoint site. The SharePoint site was created automatically when the Microsoft team was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found using the UI in the SharePoint site was to click on the site title, and then scroll down on the popup that shows and under "Apps" click on "Teams" to get a link to navigate to the actual team.

I did tinker around and bit and found out that you can craft a link using F12 developer tools which can get you the same link as above.

Use the console-tab and paste this and press enter. Copy the link that are returned into a new browser tab and you will find the link at the property called `MicrosoftTeams.TeamHomeURL`.

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.Directory.DirectorySession/Group('" + _spPageContextInfo.groupId + "')?$select=teamsResources";
```